# XCode 9 is using framework that I deleted?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

Recently I installed latest XCode 9 and updated my project to Swift 4. I was using Alamofire and I updated it as well.
After that I deleted the whole Alamofire and my project still runs fine.

What I have done:
1. Deleted all the Alamofire files completely
2. Deleted it from embeded binaries and frameworks
3. Deleted it from build phases
4. Searched for Alamofire using ctrl+shift+o and Could not find any reference
5 Disabled Swift 3 @objc inferencing

What I want to achieve:
I want to delete it completely and install it via Coco pods since my previous installation was manual.

The weird thing is that my project now runs without any issues and warnings and the app does not crash. Also, I can still import it and use it as it is still in the XCode.

Comment: Tried doing a Clean All of the project?

Comment: I did, but it does not work either.

Comment: I have the same problem with Xcode 11.7, did you manage to fix it?